# Is it possible to pause and resume Kafka Stream conditionally?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a requirement as stated @ https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#window-final-results for waiting until window is closed in order to handle late out of order event by buffering it for duration of window.

Per my understanding of this feature is once windowing is created, the window works like wall clock processing, e.g. Creating for 1 hour window, The window starts ticking once first event comes. This 1hr window is closed exactly one hour later and all the events buffered so far will be forwarded to down stream. However, i need to be able to hold this window even longer say conditionally for as long as required e.g. based on state / information in external system such as database.

To be precise my requirement for event forwarding is (windows of 1 hour if external state record says it is good) or (hold for as long as required until external record says it's good and resume tracking of the event until the event make it fully 1hr, disregarding the time when external system is not good)
To elaborate this 2nd condition, e.g. if my window duration 1 1hr , my event starts at 00:00, if on 00:30 it is down and back normal on 00:45, the window should extend until 01:15.

Is it possible to pause and resume the forwarding of events conditionally based on my requirement above ? 
Do I have to use transformation / processor and use value store manually to track the first processing time of my event and conditionally forwarding buffered events in punctuator ?

I appreciate all kind of work around and suggestion for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> the window works like wall clock processing

No. Kafka Streams work on event-time, hence, the timestamps as returned from the `TimestampExtractor` (by default the embedded record timestamp) are use to advance time.

> To be precise my requirement for event forwarding is (windows of 1 hour if external state record says it is good)

This would need a custom solution IMHO.

> or (hold for as long as required until external record says it's good and resume tracking of the event until the event make it fully 1hr, disregarding the time when external system is not good)

Not 100% if I understand this part.

> Is it possible to pause and resume the forwarding of events conditionally based on my requirement above ?

No.

> Do I have to use transformation / processor and use value store manually to track the first processing time of my event and conditionally forwarding buffered events in punctuator ?

I think this might be required.

Check out this blog post, that explains how `suppress()` work in details, and when it emits based on observed event-time: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers