# Pause partition in Kafka Streams (Processor API)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There have been [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609727/is-it-possible-to-pause-and-resume-kafka-stream-conditionally) [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484811/is-there-any-way-we-can-pause-kafka-stream-for-certain-period-and-resume-later) of question here on SO and elsewhere about pausing and resuming of partitions in Kafka Streams, the answer being "no, you can't pause partitions in Streams", however implicitly or explicitly assuming the Kafka Streams DSL.

I'm interested in whether this is true for the PAPI (Processor API) as well. Streams is pausing and resuming partitions internally, but I wonder if this is controllable by a Processor.

My topology is this:

```
┌──────────┐┌──────────┐
│in topic 1││in topic 2│
└┬─────────┘└┬─────────┘
┌▽───────────▽──┐       
│merge processor│       
└┬──────────────┘       
┌▽────────┐             
│out topic│             
└─────────┘
```

<sup>(made using [Diagon](https://arthursonzogni.com/Diagon/#GraphDAG))</sup>

The input topics are co-partitioned, and `merge processor` is supposed to decide, based on the contents of the data received, to always process from the partition with older data (until they reach parity and then it's the other partitions turn). In other words, I want to control the pace of consumption per partition, based on their contents, relative to each other.

As the processor isn't able to decide which partition to receive from - it is just called and needs to accept whatever comes in - it cannot apply back pressure, which  `StreamTask` would actually be able to handle (it is pausing and resuming partitions based on the partition buffer size).

So is there a way to do this in Streams PAPI, or is this too low-level? But it would appear the higher level DSL would have to do something similar in order to do joining and windowing...